# Permeability anisotropy of porous media

Tags: fluid-dynamics, porous-media

Imagine if one were to cut a cylindrical plug out of a perfectly homogeneous rock exactly along one of the principal axis of permeability anisotropy, specifically Kmax. Then, imagine inserting only one end of the plug partially into tubing to supply fluid pressure and flow along the core's long axis. The remainder of the core is left unconfined/unjacketed. The long axis of the plug is oriented inline with the gravity field, vertically downward. Thus, the direction of flow is oriented inline with the flow potential gradient at the inlet end of the plug. Should one expect flow to exit only out the other end face of the plug and no flow to exit the outer periphery of the plug?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if gravity effects were negligible?

Comment: @ChesterMiller well, regardless of gravity effects, I think the particles of fluid will travel some distance orthogonal to vertically downward  as they must travel around rock grains to keep traveling downward. Also, the pressure gradient in all directions just beyond the inlet is influenced by the 1 atmosphere boundary condition of the plug's unconfined surfaces. I'm not sure how capillary pressure would play a role in all of this. Per intuition I would expect flow to exit all surfaces of the plug, regardless of orientation with the gravity field.

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: @ChesterMiller For high permeability anisotropy I would expect the majority the injected fluid mass to exit the other end-face of the plug as Kmax offers the least resistance to flow. However, I would expect this result would be dependent on the length-diameter dimensions of the plug, with less mass exiting the end face as the length of the plug increases (with a constant diameter) as the dp/dL along the long axis would decrease

Comment: I totally agree again.